# How can I save function calls in a list and call them one by one in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am saving my function call like this

```
val savedFun = { myFunction("Ali", "ali@test.com") }
```

I can call it latter like this `savedFun()` and its working perfectly fine.
But I want to save multiple calls in a list and then call them one by one. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to store your functions in a `List<() -> Unit>`:

```
val listOfFun: MutableList<() -> Unit> = mutableListOf()

listOfFun += { myFunction("Ali", "ali@test.com") }
listOfFun += { myFunction("AnotherPerson", "another_person@test.com") }
```

And execute your functions from the list:

```
listOfFun.forEach { it() }
```